# Capacitor phase delay caused by releasing stored charge slower than the voltage source?

Tags: capacitor, ac

Capacitors cause phase delay on circuit downstreams of them. Is this because the capacitor is releasing its stored energy more slowly than the voltage source? As seen in square wave example. If yes, why does it release charge slower than the voltage source? Seems like with electrons stuff happens so fast, but not here.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) article on R-C circuits will clear things up.

Comment: Any content that had good explanations usually clear things up, Wikipedia often has good articles, but they are rarely the best on the web. The internet is pretty large these days :)

Comment: What I really wonder is just why there is phase delay, and, explained in a way that is actually easily understood. It is usually possible to explain things easily, but it is also possible to explain them in a way that makes no sense unless you already familiarized yourself with a lot of concepts. Since I know I have always been able to find an easy explanation to everything, that anyone can get, I know there is one for this as well.

Comment: One thing I get now after looking at falstad circuit simulator is that it is being charged slower and slower, as it reaches half of voltage source the current has reached half of initial current, etc

Comment: I think I get it now. In AC, when the voltage starts going down from peak, there will be a reverse voltage from the capacitor, before the AC generator starts to reach 0 voltage and go negative. This is probably why the voltage phase "lags".

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is the exponential voltage change of an RC circuit when driven by a square wave.  The phase delay you are talking about is due to the current into the capacitor being proportional to the rate of change of voltage across the capacitor's terminals, which is somewhat related but not exactly the same.

Comment: I know the square wave is different. I said that in the question too. The reason I show it is as an example of the delay. What I ask as second part of question is why charging and discharging is delayed and slower for the capacitor. Usually things happen really fast with electricity, but as in square wave example it takes enough time to actually be very visible.

Comment: If the actual time it takes to charge capacitor is proportional to the current in ampere, then it explains it. I just do not see intuitively that it holds enough charge for that but I guess it must?